# Is it possible that the RestAPI can accept a Request from a specific file?

Tags: javascript, java, http, https, microprofile

I would like to create an API to accept only the specific requests from the specific HTML I had provided.

Following is an example;
[image]

My idea is to add a ssh-key to the Header.

The problem would be that if the key is released and other request uses the same, then the HTML no longer has meaningful...

Comment: Just validate the key that your specific HTML is sending?

Comment: @SachinGorade Yes, I still don't know what should I use. I am looking for likes JWT.